# How can I find the indices of the intersetion of data frames in R efficiently?

Tags: r

I have the following setting (a toy example if my real problem):

```
data1 = data.frame(cbind(1:8,1:8+3,1:8+5))
data2 = data.frame(rbind(c(4,7,9),c(7,10,12)))
```

thus

```
> data1
  X1 X2 X3
1  1  4  6
2  2  5  7
3  3  6  8
4  4  7  9
5  5  8 10
6  6  9 11
7  7 10 12
8  8 11 13
```

and

```
> data2
  X1 X2 X3
1  4  7  9
2  7 10 12
```

How can I find the indices if the rows of `data2` in `data1` efficiently? The result in the above example should be `c(4,7)`.
I tried looping but this is just too inefficient. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Here is a whole comparison between different approaches. You can easily adjust them to find the same rows and not the differences. https://www.r-bloggers.com/identifying-records-in-data-frame-a-that-are-not-contained-in-data-frame-b-%E2%80%93-a-comparison/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `which` with `%in%`

```
which(do.call(paste, data1) %in% do.call(paste, data2))
#[1] 4 7
```

Or do a join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1, keep.rownames = TRUE)[data2, on = names(data2)]$rn
#[1] "4" "7"
```

Comment: Just a precision. for `setDT` you need to load `data.table` package. It is not base functions

Answer (score 3):

Another base R approach would be this:

```
x <- rbind(data1, data2)
which(duplicated(x, fromLast=TRUE))

#[1] 4 7
```

And a non-base-R approach, which gives you the right result (not the number of the rows, but the values of the rows)

```
library(compare)
comparison <- compare(data1,data2,allowAll=TRUE)
comparison$tM
#     X1 X2 X3
#   1  1  4  6
#   2  2  5  7
```

Comment: The `duplicated` method for `data.frame`s uses `paste` similarly to the @akrun's answer. Furthermore, your line could bring false positives if `data1` contains duplicated rows not present in `data2`.

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr`

```r
data1 = data.frame(cbind(1:8,1:8+3,1:8+5))
data2 = data.frame(rbind(c(4,7,9),c(7,10,12)))
library(dplyr)
data1 %>% 
  # add a row id
  mutate(rowID = row_number()) %>%
  # keep only rows of data1 that are in data2
  semi_join(data2) %>%
  # keep one row ID
  select(rowID)
#> Joining, by = c("X1", "X2", "X3")
#>   rowID
#> 1     4
#> 2     7
```